# Saving JSON response globally accessible

Tags: android, json, model, pojo

I have integrated one web-service. Parsed the data using GSON and initialized model/pojo class.

Now, I have requirement to access that Model/Pojo class globally all over the application.

I want that class to check various things in separate activities and fragments.

How can I make that model/pojo class accessible all over the app?

Thanks.

Comment: Where I work we do this by making the model a statically enforced singleton. You could also use dependency injection if you're up to it. But why is your model class checking things in your activities and fragments? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: @TheMonkeyKing Checking to manage options according to assign Roles to User.

Comment: How about using a cache? (e.g. Redis)

Comment: @LHCHIN Please explain about it.

Comment: create setter and getter in your application class and access through out the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the DataSource class singleton and use it in your app:

```java
public class JsonDataSource {
    private static JsonDataSource instance = new JsonDataSource();

    // your json data model
    private JsonData data;

   // private constructor to prevent creating new instances
    private JsonDataSource() { 
    }

    public static JsonDataSource getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public JsonData getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(JsonData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

then you can use like this

```java
// set data
JsonDataSource.getInstance().setData(jsonData);

// get data
JsonData data =  JsonDataSource.getInstance().getData();
```

Comment: I encourage you to look into [Dagger2](https://github.com/google/dagger), It makes these kind of things more easy and reduces boilerplate code

Comment: Thanks for the Dagger Suggestion. I can implement this also with RXBus. But this project is for Freshers. By the Way, With your solution What happens when user kills the app? I think I need to re-call the web service in main dashboard. Isn't it.?

Answer (score 1):

```
Simple and easy way Just create getter and setter in your root Application Class
and access it globally within the application using getter method

private String jsonData;

 public String getmJsonData()
    {
        return jsonData;
    }

    public void setjsonData(String jsonData) {
        this.jsonData= jsonData;
    }


//Set Data

((Your_application_class)getApplicationContext()).setjsonData(data);

//get Data

((Your_application_class)getApplicationContext()).getjsondata());
```

Comment: Viaks Sir, What happens if user kills the app ?

Comment: if app kill from recent  task then data also destroyed , if u want to save data for all time then only database and preference is the option

Answer (score 0):

save your json to SharedPreferences.
try this:

```
    public class MySessionManager {
    public Context context;
    private final String PREF_SD_INFO = "Share_Preference";
    private final String KEY_DEF = "KEY_PRE";
    public MySessionManager(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

//save your json data
public void setSongs(SongsList songs) {
            if (context != null) {
                SharedPreferences LoginPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_SD_INFO, 
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = LoginPref.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                songsLists.add(songs);
                String json = gson.toJson(songsLists);
                editor.putString(KEY_PRE, json);
                editor.apply();

            }


//get your json data
    public ArrayList<SongsList> getSongs() {
            if (context != null) {
                SharedPreferences LoginPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_SD_INFO, 
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = LoginPref.getString(KEY_PRE, null);
                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<SongsList>>() {
                }.getType();
                return gson.fromJson(json, type);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't think this is what shared preferences is for. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#pref

Comment: @TheMonkeyKing I also thinking so. Can we make local db using SQLite ? for such.

Comment: @JaiminModi This is one of way to your solution. You can also use room version for this.

Comment: @JaiminModi I already told you my two ideas. Statically enforced singleton or dependency injection. I've dealt with similar use cases at work and those are the two solutions I've come up with.

Comment: @TheMonkeyKing I have basic idea about making Singleton. But, confused regarding initializing it while parsing the response.

Comment: @JaiminModi You could also look into Volley. I know it can cache certain json requestions, so you might be able to just make the same api request from multiple views and have the subsequent calls get data from the cache. You'd have to understand how that caching works though, because I don't.